# Can I use the bigQuery command line tool in GCP to do ETL work?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'd like to ask you a question about the bigQuery of the Google Cloud platform.

The work I want to do is ETL using bq load.

ETL refers to extraction, transformation, and loading.

Specifically
I would like to add a column within the data in JSON format. Also, I want to change the data type of the added column.

for example

```
{
Cookie: 'test_cookie'
Time: "2020-10-26 00:00 UTC"
Data named }
```

already exists.

Here

```
{
Cookie: 'test_cookie'
dt: "2020-10-26"
hour : 00
timestamp : "2020-10-26 00:00 UTC"
}
```

about to perform a data ETL operation this way.

I'm posting a question because it's hard to find anything related to Google Cloud Platform documents.

Is it possible to do the above work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do most of that with the bq command line tool.  There is a couple ways you could handle it.

1. Do some unix scripting to wrap the whole process, reserving the bq command line tool to perform your load.  This being more of an ETL scenario.
2. Take more of an ELT approach and load your data first into a stage table then manipulate it within BigQuery using some of the date functions to parse out the time column and load the resulting data.

The documentation on GCP is fairly robust, here are some links that may help you get started:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-command-line

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/bigquery-cli#0